# How to convert a haskell List into a monadic function that uses list values for operations?

Tags: haskell

I am having trouble wrapping my head around making to work a conversion of a list into a monadic function that uses values of the list.

For example, I have a list `[("dir1/content1", "1"), ("dir1/content11", "11"), ("dir2/content2", "2"), ("dir2/content21", "21")]` that I want to be converted into a monadic function that is mapped to a following `do` statement:

```
do
   mkBlob ("dir1/content1", "1")
   mkBlob ("dir1/content11", "11")
   mkBlob ("dir2/content2", "2")
   mkBlob ("dir2/content21", "21")
```

I imagine it to be a function similar to this:

```
contentToTree [] = return 
contentToTree (x:xs) = (mkBlob x) =<< (contentToTree xs)
```

But this does not work, failing with an error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘() -> TreeT LgRepo m ()’
              with actual type ‘TreeT LgRepo m ()’
• Possible cause: ‘(>>=)’ is applied to too many arguments
  In the expression: (mkBlob x) >>= (contentToTree xs)
  In an equation for ‘contentToTree’:
      contentToTree (x : xs) = (mkBlob x) >>= (contentToTree xs)
• Relevant bindings include
    contentToTree :: [(TreeFilePath, String)] -> () -> TreeT LgRepo m ()
```

I do not quite understand how to make it work.

Here is my relevant code:

```
import Data.Either
import Git
import Data.Map
import Conduit
import qualified Data.List as L
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import Control.Monad (join)

type FileName = String 
    
data Content = Content {
  content :: Either (Map FileName Content) String
} deriving (Eq, Show) 

contentToPaths :: String -> Content -> [(TreeFilePath, String)]
contentToPaths path (Content content) = case content of
  Left m -> join $ L.map (\(k, v) -> (contentToPaths (if L.null path then k else path ++ "/" ++ k) v)) $ Data.Map.toList m
  Right c -> [(BS.pack path, c)]

mkBlob :: MonadGit r m => (TreeFilePath, String) -> TreeT r m ()
mkBlob (path, content) = putBlob path
    =<< lift (createBlob $ BlobStream $
              sourceLazy $ BL.fromChunks [BS.pack content])

sampleContent = Content $ Left $ fromList [
  ("dir1", Content $ Left $ fromList [
    ("content1", Content $ Right "1"),
    ("content11", Content $ Right "11")
    ]),
  ("dir2", Content $ Left $ fromList [
    ("content2", Content $ Right "2"),
    ("content21", Content $ Right "21")
    ])
  ]
```

Would be grateful for any tips or help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have:

- A list of values of some type `a` (in this case `a ~ (String, String)`). So, `xs :: [a]`
- A function `f` from `a` to some type `b` in a monadic context, `m b`. Since you're ignoring the return value, we can imagine `b ~ ()`. So, `f :: Monad m => a -> m ()`.

You want to perform the operation, yielding some monadic context and an unimportant value, `m ()`. So overall, we want some function `doStuffWithList :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m ()) -> m ()`. We can [search Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+(a+-%3E+m+())+-%3E+m+()) for this type, and it yields some results. Unfortunately, as we've chosen to order the arguments, the first several results are little-used functions from other packages. If you scroll further, you start to find stuff in `base` - very promising. As it turns out, the function you are looking for is [`traverse_ :: (Foldable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f ()`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_). With that, we can replace your do-block with just:

```
traverse_ mkBlob [ ("dir1/content1", "1")
                 , ("dir1/content11", "11")
                 , ("dir2/content2", "2")
                 , ("dir2/content21", "21")
                 ]
```

As it happens there are many names for this function, some for historical reasons and some for stylistic reasons. `mapM_`, `forM_`, and `for_` are all the same and all in `base`, so you could use any of these. But the `M_` versions are out of favor these days because really you only need `Applicative`, not `Monad`; and the `for` versions take their arguments in an order that's convenient for lambdas but inconvenient for named functions. So, `traverse_` is the one I'd suggest.

Comment: Had to add the `(MonadGit r m) =>` constraint to the function type and it worked: 
`contentToTree :: (MonadGit r m) => Content -> TreeT r m ()`
`contentToTree content = traverse_ mkBlob (contentToPaths "" content)`
Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `mkBlob` is a function that looks like

```
mkBlob :: (String, String) -> M ()
```

where `M` is some specific monad, then you have the list

```
xs = [("dir1/content1", "1"), ("dir1/content11", "11"), ("dir2/content2", "2"), ("dir2/content21", "21")]
```

whose type is `xs :: [(String, String)]`. The first thing we need is to run the `mkBlob` function on *each* element, i.e. via `map`.

```
map mkBlob xs :: [M ()]
```

Now, we have a list of monadic actions, so we can use [`sequence`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence) to run them in sequence.

```
sequence (map mkBlob xs) :: M [()]
```

The resulting `[()]` value is all but useless, so we can use [`void`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:void) to get rid of it

```
void . sequence . map mkBlob $ xs :: M ()
```

Now, `void . sequence` is called `sequence_` in Haskell (since this pattern is fairly common), and `sequence . map` is called `mapM`. Putting the two together, the function you want is called [`mapM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mapM_).

```
mapM_ mkBlob xs :: M ()
```